# jQuery to show images in sequence in a div depending on their ID

Tags: jquery

I am having total 10 images with `ID`'s in a `div`. Now I want to show those images depending on `arrow` keypress in a specific sequence `1a, cv2, w3i, e4, re5, we6i, w7i, w8i, in, xxi` irrespective of their position in div. Now, when the arrow press second time then it should show second image in that series. Also, if the image in the div are less than 10 suppose 4. Then also, they should show in the same sequence as they show, when there were 10 imges. Please look at my example,

```js
$("img").hide();
//pressing arrow button first time
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 39) {
  //show 1a
  //if 1a does not exist, then show cv2
  //if 1a,cv2 does not exist, then show w3i
  //if 1a,cv2,w3i does not exist, then show e4
  //and so on.
  }
});

//pressing arrow button second time
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 39) {
  //show the second img in series after as first already shown in first press
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Example1: If div has 10 images -->
<div class="img">
  <img id="xxi" src="#">
  <img id="re5" src="#">
  <img id="w8i" src="#">
  <img id="w3i" src="#">
  <img id="we6i" src="#">
  <img id="1a" src="#">
  <img id="w7i" src="#">
  <img id="in" src="#">
  <img id="cv2i" src="#">
  <img id="e4" src="#">
</div>

<!-- Example2: If div has 4 images -->
<div class="img">
  <img id="w3" src="#">
  <img id="w7" src="#">
  <img id="1a" src="#">
  <img id="e4" src="#">
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask] and revise to be more clear about the problem.

Comment: Also, put dummy images in your demo so we can see it. There are many services to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated question is a bit confusing because you added `in, xxi` in which I don't see any number number-based logic will fail. However, I found your question interesting, So I tried it.

Here is my example, I am getting all the hidden images from the selector then I am mapping the selectors' ids and also extracting the number from ids and saving it as `index` then I am sorting by index. once sorting is done. I pop the first object mapped array and then I get the ID from the array and I use jquery to show that image ID.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.img > img').hide();

  const showNext = ($el) => {
    const els = $($el + ' > img:not(:visible)');
    if (els.length) {
      const ids = els
        .map(function() {
          const id = this.id;
          return {
            id: id,
            index: id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),
          };
        })
        .get()
        .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);

      $($el + ' > img#' + ids[0].id).show();
    }
  };

  //pressing arrow button first time
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 39) {
      showNext('#first-container');
      showNext('#second-container');
    }
  });
})($);
```

```css
.img {
  display: grid;
  gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  counter: img;
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  counter-increment: img;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-4">
    <h3>Press right arrow key to see the images</h3>
    <!-- Example1: If div has 10 images -->
    <div class="img" id="first-container">
      <img id="10i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=10i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="5i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=5i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="8i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=8i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="3i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=3i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="6i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=6i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="1i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=1i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="7i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=7i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="9i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=9i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="2i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=2i" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="4i" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=4i" width="150" height="150" />
    </div>

    <!-- Example2: If div has 4 images -->
    <div class="img" id="second-container">
      <img id="i3" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=i3" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="i7" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=i7" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="i1" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=i1" width="150" height="150" />

      <img id="i4" src="https://placehold.jp/150x150.png?text=i4" width="150" height="150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my `img` id are random, not like you have given in your example, which includes numbers and the alphabet only. How this program will work if there are purly random ID to the img. I think first we can store our ID priprity list in some array and then get values from that array to show them in required sequence. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't complete the data of your product that you're working with, so I can't suggest any logic here. you'll have to figure out the logic.

Comment: But sir, how can we do it, if our img id are toally random, not like you have given in your example.

Comment: I don't know man. I don't know what your product is, how you get ids and what pattern they have. as I already mentioned, your question is confusing as it doesn't have the necessary data to solve it. I just tried it because I find it interesting with your original post(before edits).